How to prove that a Lie algebra-valued differential form is exact for the covariant derivative
Given a differential $p$-form $\omega^A$ over a smooth manifold with values on some Lie algebra, I wanted to know how could one prove that it can be written as an exact form for the exterior covariant derivative, i.e. $\omega^A=\mathcal{D}\alpha^A$ for some $(p-1)$-form $\alpha^A$ where $\mathcal{D}=d-A$ is the covariant exterior derivative.
In the special case where the differential forms do not have values on any Lie algebra, one usually tries to prove that $\omega$ is closed, and via Poincaré lemma it will be locally exact. Evidently this argument will not work for the Lie algebra valued case and I have no idea on how to procceed.
What I have tried
I tried to get some kind of integrability condition by applying twice the covariant derivative, so that $$ \mathcal{D}\omega^A=\mathcal{D}\mathcal{D}\alpha^A $$ and using the relation bewteen $\mathcal{D}^2$ and the curvature of the connection. The problem is that even if $\omega^A$ satisfies this condition, I am not sure this is a sufficient condition.
What I'm asking
I'm asking for sufficient conditions on $\omega^A$ that would guarantee that it can be written as $\mathcal{D}\alpha^A$ for some $(p-1)$-form $\alpha^A$, at least locally.

I voted to move this to MSE: there is no physics in this version of the question.

Is your connection flat by any chance? Otherwise, see my answer here for some necessary conditions and a conjecture.

@MoisheKohan No, I was thinking about a general connection. Thanks for the link. Do you know any particular reference which deals with this or a similar problem?

No, I do not...

Take a look here. I have no idea how solid this paper is.
